# How to for loop meta_query array value WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code

```
                $today = date('d');
                $tomorrow = date('d', strtotime('+ 1 day'));
                $thedayaftertomorrow = date('d', strtotime('+ 2 day'));
                $current_month = date('m');
                $next_month = date('m', strtotime('+ 1 month'));
                $args = array (
                  'posts_per_page' => 4,  // number of posts   
                  'post_type'      => 'employees', // your custom post type
                  'meta_key'       => 'birthday',  // your custom date field name
                  'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
                  'order'          => 'ASC',
                  'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $current_month . $today,
                    ),
                    array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $current_month . $tomorrow,
                    ),
                    array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $current_month . $thedayaftertomorrow,
                    ), 
                    array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $next_month . '[0-9]{2}',
                    ),
                  )
                );
```

I want to use for loop to add next 30 days to the array value, instead of repeating the values, cureently I'm using $today, $tomorrow and $thedayaftertomorrow to add new days.

Comment: Something like `for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {$date('...', strtotime('+' . $i . ' days')); ...}`?

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: So you're doing something wrong. Try to study basic cycles.

Comment: What the date format for this birthday meta?

Comment: Date format is 'Ymd'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
for ($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
$date->modify('+1 day');
$args["meta_query"][] =  array(
                      'key'      => 'birthday',
                      'compare'  => 'REGEXP',
                      'value'    => '[0-9]{4}' . $date->format('dm'),
                    );
}
```